# Parse Array Formated String as an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am having an array formatted string stored in a variable where i need to convert it in to real array

here is my code

```
$hello ="array( 
    'numberposts' => -1, 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'meta_query' => array( 
        'relation' => 'AND',
             array( 
                'key' => 'subject_id', 
                'value' => 'CE6301', 
                'compare' => '=' 
                ),
             array( 
                'key' => 'regulation', 
                'value' => '2013', 
                'compare' => '=' 
                ),
             )
    )";
```

So here is an array that i need to convert as formated array in php

So when my array is printed it should look something like this

```
Array ( [numberposts] => -1 [post_type] => post [meta_query] => Array ( [relation] => AND [0] => Array ( [key] => subject_id [value] => CE6301 [compare] => = ) [1] => Array ( [key] => regulation [value] => 2013 [compare] => = ) ) )
```

What function i have to use in php to convert string array into an normal array

Comment: `eval()`. But be sure to read up on that.

Comment: @Martijn Nice, I wouldn't have thought of that

Comment: saving it to JSON before that would be better though.

Comment: If you can help it, you may want to step back and choose JSON over an "array formatted string."  It seems you are seeking a solution to a problem which you are creating.

Comment: eval function is not working , even i parsed as json_encode() not working, i encoded as JSON and i used eval, printing same like normal string but not as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you got hold of this but you can use `eval()` on this one. Just modify the string a little bit to create a valid array in the end. Example:

```
$hello ="array( 
    'numberposts' => -1, 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'meta_query' => array( 
        'relation' => 'AND',
             array( 
                'key' => 'subject_id', 
                'value' => 'CE6301', 
                'compare' => '=' 
                ),
             array( 
                'key' => 'regulation', 
                'value' => '2013', 
                'compare' => '=' 
                ),
             )
)";

$hello = '$hello = ' . $hello . ';';
eval($hello);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($hello);
```

Comment: As like same i have tried the eval function , but not works for me, but i copied your code it works perfect, Anyway Thank you ghost this is what i expected

Comment: Again, read some info about `eval()`, you could potentially create a security problem. Eval should a last-option-solution only.